# bring DIV forward on hover inside a jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, css

i have a table within a jScrollPane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com). On the table i have an image, so when the user hovers over it shows a text bubble.

This works fine but the problem is when i hover over the image the bubble gets cuts off. What i need to do is when its hovered to completely bring the bubble forward without getting hidden or cut off inside the `jspContainer`

Although i tried to set a higher `z-index` value for the `.bubble` it doesn't seem to be working.

But when i increase the container height of `jspContainer` the bubble is completely visible but i need to bring it forward without increasing the height

I have made a sample fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/x9dcgthp/3/

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: where is that image?

Comment: Your js fiddle doesn't seem to match what your talking about. Please share the exact code that your scenario depicts for us to help.

Comment: @NasirT sorry i hadnt updated the draft in the fiddle.. here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/x9dcgthp/3/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you lose jScrollPane and deal with the default scrollbars instead. The only way jScrollPane can remove the scrollbar and replace it with is own is by setting the container to `overflow: hidden;` and manually handling scroll events, which means anything that goes beyond that container will be clipped off. If you force the container to have a visible overflow, jScrollPane will stop working.

You have a few workarounds however, but I don't suggest all of them.

- You can put the tooltips outside the jscrollpane container, although you'd have to manually move it on scroll and position it accordingly causing in much more overhead and page unresponsiveness.
- You can have a single tooptip object outside the jscrollpane which you activate/deactivate on click/hover of the icons. This will, again, lead to much more overhead and unmaintainable code.
- You can increase the height of your jScrollPane then add padding to it and move the tooltip to the center instead of being below the icon. It's possible this will still have overflowing contents, however.
- You can instead cover the data row on hover/click instead of showing the tooltip below the icon. This way it's completely visible although it goes against proper UI/UX principles.
- You can create your own custom jScrollPane implementation which allows bleeding content. This will double your workload though, and still will result in a worse performance.

In the end, losing jScrollPane is still the best option, as built-in scrollbars don't define the overall design direction you're going for. Moreover, some modern browsers are already hiding the scrollbars and replacing them with much nicer elements when it appears on scrollable containers.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue of the jspcontainer height you are having is not because of z-index but because you are calling the `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();` while the data table is being rendered which causes the javascript to set the height of the jScrollPane for the 1 or 2 rows that where only rendered during that time.

You need to add the call in a `$(document).ready()` function so that the pane is initialized after all the elements on the page related to it have been rendered. Or add this call at the end of the page.

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

Now i think you can work around the css to get the bubble alignment setup as you want. :)

Also here is a bit modified code of yours that i had worked a bit on to adjust. http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/RGdrbB

Hope this helps.